# A simple German Beer recipe

Tags: beer, first-time-brewer

I'm new to brewing. I've got the gear and no idea. I'm doing alright with a hard cider at the moment thanks to the support I've received here. So I'm starting to think about my next adventure.

I'd like to attempt a German Beer, blond rather than dark. Any recipe suggestions for a novice?

Comment: All grain or extract?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Robert said about cooling. Stay away from ***Lagers*** until you get some experience and most important heating and cooling for lager fermentation. Lagers require a diacetyl rest where you usually need heating in addition to cooling.

A Blonde Ale was actually my very first brew. I recommend getting an ***Ale*** extract kit that has some steeping grains to get your feet wet with some actual grains, and how to use brew bags. Then it's an easy step to all grain Brew In A Bag.

There's a lot of great books on how to get started. *John Palmers How to Brew*, is one of the best for a good over view for the nivice and reference for the advanced brewer a like.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you purchase [Brewing Classic Styles](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0937381926). It covers 80+ recipes with lots of details. While you are at it, buy [How To Brew](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0937381888). That will teach you how to make great beer.

For recipes, go to http://beersmithrecipes.com/

Answer (score 1):

Many Pilsner or Helles recipes only use Pilsen Malt (e.g., 4kg) and one kind of hops (e.g., 30 and 40 grams of Hallertauer pellets). Or try a German wheat beer. A web search will turn up plenty of recipes.

As a beginner you probably don't have cooling like a chest freezer for fermentation, but depending on where you live you may have a garage or basement that is cold enough (but not too cold).

Answer (score 0):

Try brewing with extract first - less equipment needed and the beer produced is as fine as any other. One can produce a good beer and even a fine lager with simple equipment and it is not as difficult as it is often said. Pre-hopped extract kits are easy on the brain and the palate. As confidence improves moving to just extract and steeped grains and loose hops is a natural progression. On can go on to all grain brewing but IMHO there is little extra to be gained - however "authentic" the process might be.